# CakeDataGridder set named parameter with the pagination link

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I am using https://github.com/BradCrumb/CakeDataGridder...

I would like to send a named parameter with the pagination link. At present my pagination link is "courses/trainees/page:2". I would like to set it to "courses/trainees/2/type:new/page:2".

Comment: Can't you use query strings? Named params should be avoided since 2.0 if possible.

Comment: What is type:new? Is it a field from your table;